# trying to do check against sqlite database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to create a high score functionality for my android game

I am trying to check against sqlite db, using a cursor to go through a query to match it against a string. If there is a match in the name I want it to just update the score if it is higher.

If there is no match in the name, then I want it to enter the name and score as a new high score.

After putting in breakpoints however, regardless of the name already being there it adds the new score. So my check to see if the name exists is not working.

This is the snippet of code from my class where I perform all database functions,

```
SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // I store the name string in the game as a ContentValue called queryValues to use here
            // I use a cursor to go through query

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT whichPlayer FROM highScore";
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if ((queryValues.get("whichPlayer").equals(cursor.moveToNext()))) { 

            // The code here is to update score, as the check above should denote that a name already exists
            // However it goes straight to the else (To enter a new player)
```

I don't know where I am going wrong here, as no errors are being shown so there is a problem with my logic. I'm fairly new to programming so it's probably a silly error

Any more code  needed for question clarity?

Any help would be appreciated.

after trying albertsmuktupavels answer I get

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(26483): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 E/AndroidRuntime(26483): Process: com.example.con4, PID: 26483
 E/AndroidRuntime(26483): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0
 E/AndroidRuntime(26483):   at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:426)
 E/AndroidRuntime(26483):   at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
 E/AndroidRuntime(26483):   at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
```

plus a little more pointing to the

```
 String checkPlayer = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("whichPlayer"));
```

Comment: `a query to match it against a string` - so, you should add a **WHERE** clause to match a name, don't you?

Comment: try cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("whichPlayer")) and then compare this value inside the condition.

Comment: can you be more specific with your questions like what exactly do you have in your database(name of fields) and with a example try to explain what exactly are you trying to achieve. And what all java files are you using??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to compare with cursor.moveToNext()? That function just returns true or false and is used to move to next row.

To get whichPlayer value from cursor use this:

```
String whichPlayer = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("whichPlayer"));
```

Than you can try to compare like this:

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
do {
    if (queryValues.get("whichPlayer").equals(whichPlayer)) {
       // ...
    }
} while (cursor.moveToFirst());
```

EDIT:
I am assuming that you have table with at least two fields and there will be only one row with score for each player.
Fields: score (integer), whichPlayer (text)

```
SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
String whichPlayer = "somePlayer";
int newScore = 4500;
// Select current player's previous score
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT score FROM highScore WHERE whichPlayer = ?", new String[] { whichPlayer });
if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() != 0) {
    // We have score in database for this player
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    // Get score for this player
    int score = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("score"));
    // Check if your new score is higher
    if (newScore > score) {
        // update your score with new one
    }
} else {
    // There is no score stored for this player - insert if you want
}
```

Comment: I have tried it like this and i got a fatal exception, i will put it on my question

Comment: added the logcat for this answer above

Comment: Updated answer. Also what is your database structure?